# Package released from sonatype, still not appearing on Maven Cetntral

Tags: gradle, sonatype, maven-central

I published from a gradle project:

```
The gradle output is below:

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
> Task :initializeSonatypeStagingRepository
Created staging repository 'orgaybgim-1002' at https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/orgaybgim-1002/content/
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 18s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

The artifact appeared in the staging repo:

[image]

Then I closed it, and released by clicking on the corresponding button. I have tried this procedure several times but the artifact still does not appear on Maven Central. What am I missing? I have reported the [issue](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-93262?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&focusedId=1281154) on sonatype JIRA but the responses are very slow.

Comment: If you haven't found a solution yet: I had this too, not with Gradle but with Maven. First you have to close the staging repository (https://central.sonatype.org/publish/release/#locate-and-examine-your-staging-repository). Under the **Activity** tab and then on the tree under **close**, you should see what the error is. In the Nexus Repository Manager you only see your package after a release if something was wrong, if you have defined an automatic release.